# Workflow approval process doesn't have ID Field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have workflow in SharePoint Designer which I use `Start Approval Process` in it.
Now I want a custom InfoPath form and write a rule in it, but the `Id` field does not exist in the form.

[image]

I don't know what happened.

Edit:

I Solved that Problem, but now when I clicked on new in "task form fields" show this Error:
Could Not Save Changes. 
[image]